# laravel putting space in table name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm getting an error that is stating my users table is invalid, I can see that there is a space in the table name at the end: 'users ' but I am unsure as to why that is. My table name in mysql is: 'users' and I have used the User model to save this data into my database.
[image]

User model:

```
    use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

I have tried explicitly stating the $table and commenting it out since the table name is it's plural and should work either way?

Section of my UserController which saves the data:

```
 $user   =   new User();
        $user->username =   Input::get('username');
        $user->password =   Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

        if($user->save())
```

Is there any possible reason why laravel is trying to put a space at the end of my users table?

Comment: Just to help debug the issue can you please try removing the Table property

Comment: done, didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the `QueryException` is about selecting data, you probably have validated data before so that the field `username` must be unique on `users` table.

Make sure that your rule contains no extra space:

```
'username' => 'unique:users'
```

Comment: Perfect! I had previously written the rule: 'required|unique:users|min:4' with spaces for formatting sake.

Comment: As optimization, add the `unique` rule at the end: `'required|min:4|unique:users'`, it may omit a database query if the value is less than four characters.